# Specify multi-select parameters (Extended Choice Parameter plugin) in jenkins Build periodically with parameters

Tags: jenkins, parameters, devops

I am trying to schedule a job to be triggered daily at 8 pm.

Currently, my `Build periodically with parameters` field looks somewhat like this:

```
0 20 * * * % name=somename; type=sometype
```

Now, I need to add another parameter called `categories` which can have multiple values, i.e., it is of the type `Multi Select` (Extended Choice Parameter plugin).

Can someone help me out with how this can be done? Thanks in advance.